# pointing a subdomain to a folder

Tags: laravel, subdomain, digital-ocean, forge

I have a laravel app hosted in forge digital ocean as a subdomain like this:

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

and the domain name is bought from another host and I point the ip given from forge digital ocean to this subdomain now i want to put my app like this

```
`subdomain.domain.com/app`
```

how can I do that ? thanks

Comment: If you're running Apache then you can follow [this article](http://mackhankins.com/blog/laravel-5-virtual-host-for-an-apache-subdirectory) to setup a virtual host for a subdirectory and if you're running nginx you can read [this article](https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/nginx-config-for-hosting-multiple-projects-in-sibling-folders/).

Comment: @Bogdan  thanks , I think this case works only for multiple projetcs as you know forge gets the app from github

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed the fact that Forge was involved, I only saw Digital Ocean :).

Comment: my application is not inside any folder it's directly hosted in github